# How can I redirect back to Flutter App from URL?

Tags: flutter, dart, paytabs

I am integrating paytabs payment gateway in my flutter application. It opens a payment page in in app browser. When the transaction is completed, it redirects to a return_url. I want to redirect back to my app, so that I can do something after the payment has been processed.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: How about you use deep link?

Comment: Try to use WebView inside an app, not to open separate browser. And I think you need backend which will process retutn_url. As a variand you must work with paytabs mobile api . And look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59605005/paytabs-payment-integration-using-dart-flutter-web-and-api

Comment: i am not sure about this,this plugin can open web url within app,it might help`https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview`@Ali Haider

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution and it worked for me!

```
InAppWebView
```

In flutter  to open the paytabs transaction page. When the transaction is successful, it redirects me to a return_url.
InAppWebView has a method

> `onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url)`

In this method, I checked if the returl_url == url and redirected to my app and closed the InAppWebView accordingly.

```
onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
          setState(() {
            _con.url = url;
          });
          if (url == "return_url") {
            //close the webview
            _con.webView.goBack();

            //navigate to the desired screen with arguments
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/OrderSuccess',
                arguments:
                    new RouteArgument(param: 'Credit Card (Paytabs)'));
          }
        },
```

Comment: this answer works fine with android, but it wont work for IOS. You need to handle the **onLoadStop** method as well to support IOS